# upload file(image) into quickblox custom object

Tags: java, android, quickblox, custom-object

How do I upload file (image) that I have his Uri, into custom object?

I've tried this:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

            HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            File newImage = new File(imageUri.toString());
            fields.put("image", newImage);
            fields.put("bla", "bla");


            QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject();
            qbCustomObject.setClassName("imageClass");  // your Class name
            qbCustomObject.setFields(fields);
            QBCustomObjects.createObject(qbCustomObject, new QBCallbackImpl() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result result) {
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        QBCustomObjectResult qbCustomObjectResult = (QBCustomObjectResult) result;
                        QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = qbCustomObjectResult.getCustomObject();
                       // Log.d("New record: ",newCustomObject.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

And I get just the string ("bla") and the image get - null

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this feature is in development brunch. Will be in master in a couple of days

But you can use it already - Download SDK from development brunch
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/development

Here are lots of snippets, especially for Custom Objects module

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/development/snippets/src/com/quickblox/snippets/modules/SnippetsCustomObjects.java

**Upload file**

```
QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject(CLASS_NAME, NOTE1_ID);
QBCustomObjectsFiles.uploadFile(file1, qbCustomObject, AVATAR_FIELD, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            QBCustomObjectFileField customObjectFileField = ((QBCOFileUploadResult) result).getCustomObjectFileField();
            Log.i(TAG, ">>>upload response:" + customObjectFileField.getFileName() + " " + customObjectFileField.getFileId() + " " +
                                customObjectFileField.getContentType());
        } else {
            handleErrors(result);
        }
   }
});
```

**Download file**

```
QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject(CLASS_NAME, NOTE1_ID);
QBCustomObjectsFiles.downloadFile(qbCustomObject, AVATAR_FIELD, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        QBFileDownloadResult downloadResult = (QBFileDownloadResult) result;
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            byte[] content = downloadResult.getContent();       // that's downloaded file content
            InputStream is = downloadResult.getContentStream(); // that's downloaded file content
            Log.i(TAG, ">>> file downloaded successfully" + getContentFromFile(is));
            if(is!=null){
                try{
                    is.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
       } else {
           handleErrors(result);
       }
    }
});
```

**Delete file**

```
QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject(CLASS_NAME, NOTE1_ID);
QBCustomObjectsFiles.deleteFile(qbCustomObject, AVATAR_FIELD, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, ">>> file deleted successfully");
        } else {
            handleErrors(result);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that help alot, i try this with "NOTE_ID" that i already created, but how do i get the "NOTE1_ID" that i just created?

Comment: You will receive it after record creation in response

QBCustomObjectResult customObjectResult = (QBCustomObjectResult) result;
QBCustomObject newCustomObject = customObjectResult.getCustomObject();

newCustomObject.getID();

Comment: Is there a way to upload file to a custom object without making a separate call to create the object first?

Comment: @kabuto178 no, for this purpose you can use Content